# Listener created after selection triggers event

Tags: java, android, events, listener

I have problem with android. I'm adding data from adapter to spinner, then I set the selection on item on position 0, after that I create `OnItemSelectedListener` and it is triggered but I don't know why...

onCreate method:

```
this.spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
this.spinner.setAdapter(MyAdapter.GetAdapter());
this.spinner.setSelection(0);

this.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       //do some things
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Maybe here is something wrong, I also try to remove the listener, change the selection and then add listener to it. Maybe I do sth wrong here:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = this.spinner.getOnItemSelectedListener();
this.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
this.spinner.setSelection(((SpinnerAdapter) this.spinner.getAdapter()).getElementIndexByTitle(array.get("ProductName")));
listener.onItemSelected(null, null, -1, -1);
this.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

It seems that it triggers the event also after: `this.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);` Maybe is there possibility to select item without triggering `OnItemSelected` ?

Comment: try it using `this.spinner.setSelection(0,false);`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that inside the AdapterView there is a SelectionNotifier and it wokrs automatically. So I need to remember last selection index and then compare it with position in `OnItemSelected`.